# WebDriver, Selenium2 - simple test failed

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I try this test:

```
@Test
public void theUserShouldBeAbleToTypeInQueryTerms() {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement queryField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    queryField.sendKeys("cats");
    queryField.submit();
    assertThat(driver.getTitle(), containsString("cats"));
}
```

but got an error:

> Failure, Expected: a string containing "cats" got: "Google"

How can I modify the test to have SUCCESS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the page with the search results hasn't loaded yet - try waiting a few seconds before running the assertion.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use WebDriverWait class. It will wait until title will be equals "cats" or timeout.
Here's an example of how it works (but you have to adjust the code for your case):

```
    public static void waitForTitle(final PageTitle title, WebDriver driver) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, TestDriver.WAIT_TIMEOUT).until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {

        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            for (WebElement we : PageHelper.findElements(WebElementLocator.pageHeader, driver)) {
                if (we.getText().equals(title.getValue())) {
                    return we;
                }
            }
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Title not found: \"" + title.getValue() + "\"");
        }
    });
}
```